# nginx unable to include ngx_http_sub_module with --with-http_sub_module

Tags: nginx, openresty

unable to include ngx_http_sub_module with --with-http_sub_module

I am compiling (the openresty bundle https://github.com/openresty/ngx_openresty) with

./configure --with-luajit --with-http_sub_module

make 
make install

and in my config file I call sub_filter,
and get the error message : unknown directive "sub_filter" when starting nginx

nginx -V does not show the sub_module in the module list :

/usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin/nginx -V

```
nginx version: openresty/1.7.7.1
built by gcc 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/usr/local/openresty/nginx --with-cc-opt='-I/tmp/ngx_openresty-1.7.7.1/build/luajit-root/usr/local/openresty/luajit/include/luajit-2.1 -O2' --add-module=../ngx_devel_kit-0.2.19 --add-module=../echo-nginx-module-0.57 --add-module=../xss-nginx-module-0.04 --add-module=../ngx_coolkit-0.2rc2 --add-module=../set-misc-nginx-module-0.27 --add-module=../form-input-nginx-module-0.10 --add-module=../encrypted-session-nginx-module-0.03 --add-module=../srcache-nginx-module-0.28 --add-module=../ngx_lua-0.9.13 --add-module=../ngx_lua_upstream-0.02 --add-module=../headers-more-nginx-module-0.25 --add-module=../array-var-nginx-module-0.03 --add-module=../memc-nginx-module-0.15 --add-module=../redis2-nginx-module-0.11 --add-module=../redis-nginx-module-0.3.7 --add-module=../rds-json-nginx-module-0.13 --add-module=../rds-csv-nginx-module-0.05 --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/openresty/luajit/lib -L/tmp/ngx_openresty-1.7.7.1/build/luajit-root/usr/local/openresty/luajit/lib' --with-http_ssl_module
```

in the configure file I see :

Options directly inherited from nginx

--with-http_sub_module enable ngx_http_sub_module